# document onclick never executes on the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to stop default button action inside the iframe, and I had luck with this approach:

```
$('#iframe').prop('contentDocument').onclick = function (e) {
    e = e ||  window.event;
    var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

    if (element.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
         return false; // prevent default action and stop event propagation
    }
}
```

For a couple of websites this works well, however I came across a website where this event handler is never executed when the button is clicked and then the form is being submitted. Generally, what could prevent this handler from firing? What should I look for? Also, registering `onclick` directly on the iframe button element and returning false won't stop default action, which is weird, but that also happens just on that one website.
And yes, all websites are in my domain, so there's no cross-domain security error.

Comment: An event bubbles up the DOM, as of that the `document` would be the last element receiving the event in the bubbling phase. If `stopPropagation` is called earlier then it won't reach the `document`.

Comment: Can you post some HTML too? The iframe and the appropriate content within it (ie the button).

Comment: @t.niese , that really could be the reason, thanks! I'll investigate further.

Comment: is iframe on different domain?

Comment: @t.niese one more question. If I open the website without the iframe, and call inside the console $('button').off() and then $('button').bind('click', function() { return false; }); This will be stop button action on the live website. However, doing the same thing when that website is loaded via iframe won't stop default action. It works for other websites but not for that one, which doesn't make sense. Everything is on the same domain.

Comment: You should not ask another (different) question in the comment, but open a new question (an if related referring to this one). Beside that: without knowing the code, I would guess, that you prevent the event in the iframe using jQuery, otherwise `$('button').off()` would not solve the problem. If that is true then you can't use the `jQuery` instance of the _parent_ document, to remove the event listeners added with the `jQuery` instance of the iframe.

Comment: OK, I think that I found what the real issue here is. Running $('button').off() inside the iframe for that particular website, doesn't seem to turn off the event handlers, and inside them is actually location change, and not the form submit. Really weird, on other websites off() works just fine.

Comment: I'm not using instance of the parent document, just didn't want to write $('#iframe').find('button').off(), thought it was obvious.